# How do I put a line break in between each value?

Tags: javascript, html

How would I put line breaks in between each one?

```js
document.getElementById("outPut").value = 
    document.getElementById("customerName").value + 
    document.getElementById("agencyName").value +
    document.getElementById("agencyID").value + 
    document.getElementById("questionsNeedsValue").value + 
    document.getElementById("troubleshooting").value + 
    document.getElementById("outcome").value + 
    document.getElementById("solution").value;
```

Comment: Where? In HTML? If so you need `<br>`. Tip: Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Comment: in wich context ? in the result ? in the code ?

Comment: @tadman if he has a way to distinguish between the values, but without HTML it's impossible to know what's going on

Comment: I am trying to copy text from other textareas to the output at the bottom of the page . When the text goes to the outbox box I want to to display information with line breaks so its not all jumbled up

Customer Name
Agency Name
Agencyt ID
Questions/Needs/Values etc

below is my codepen
https://codepen.io/Stakeley/pen/rNWQYxL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put a line break in between a standard JavaScript string, one generally uses "\n", although when dealing with HTML itself, a line break is represented by the string  `<br>`

So in your example, it's impossible to tell what's going on behind the scenes, if they are all in one parent element or not etc., but just based off of the code itself, you can simply add the string manually, in this case `<br>`

```
document
.getElementById("outPut")
.value = 
document
.getElementById("customerName")
.value +
 "<br>"+ 
document
.getElementById("agencyName")
.value//etc
```

A simpler way to handle this is by iterating through an array of ID names, for example

```
document
.getElementById("outPut")
.value = 
[
    "agencyName",
    //Etc add other IDs here
]
.map(
    x =>
        document
        .getElementById(x)
        .value
)
.join("<br>")
```

Comment: Pretty close, yeah. I'd recommend a split there, `.map(e => ...).join("<br>")` which avoids adding an extra `<br>` at the end. The advantage of this approach is way less code, plus an easy way to add or reorganize entries.

Comment: @tadman ah yes of course I forgot to join it, is this what you had in mind?

Comment: A little indentation for structure could help communicate what's going on better, but yeah! I usually leave the `[` at the end of the first line so it's clear it's a continuation, indent the contents of the array, then stick the `.map` directly on the end but that's all a style consideration. Whatever you're used to reading is fine. Your linter may dictate otherwise.